# Best Touchscreen Laptop for Tutoring During COVID Pandemic

Tags: technology-in-education, tutoring

I run a small tutoring company, and I specialize in math and science. During the pandemic, I began tutoring online using our 3 year old HP Pavilion touchscreen laptop. It has served me well using just my finger, and Zoom's whiteboard function. Unfortunately, my 7 year old daughter dropped it recently, and now the touchscreen is only half functional (think half the screen space for whiteboard functionality). I am getting by, but it is severely hampering my workflow, and as a result, I find myself feeling very nervous with my students because I am worried that the capability of my laptop is not going to hold out through the hour session. I need something else, like, now.

Years ago, I remember my dynamics professor used one of the first touchscreen 2-in-1 laptops in class, and to this day I think about the importance of functioning technology in supporting students in learning STEM subjects. I need a new laptop as soon as possible, but am overwhelmed by the options (my professor likely only had the one option since it was so new).

What are you all using? How is it supporting your teaching capabilities. I've done research on several options but am having severe trouble deciding because cost is, of course, a factor for my small business. I prefer something that can securely handle the myriad files associated with running a small business, but with a nice big sturdy touchscreen that I can easily use to draw diagrams and equations on without feeling cramped. Help! Note: I do NOT need it to run specific kinds of higher level STEM software, as that is not business my specialty.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Educators! Is your question specifically about tutoring during the COVID-19 pandemic or would it apply under other circumstances when teaching remotely?

Comment: Also, are you prepared to consider drawing tablets?

Comment: Does either of the following help: (1) https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/14625/, (2) https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8064

Comment: A drawing tablet would be a much less expensive solution than any laptop you could buy.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for all the responses. Regarding @J W's question, I have been tutoring for years but only begun remote tutoring during COVID 19, so upon further reflection, this would probably be hardware used for teaching remotely anytime. I HAD NOT considered a drawing tablet, but that seems like a BRILLIANT option for me, Thanks for the suggestion! I also read the link provided by @XanderHenderson. I think the software mentioned in that thread is above my pay grade both literally and figuratively, but in the future, and if the costs ever comes down, I may reconsider. Thanks all!